Freezing carbonated water - what happens to the bicarbonate content?
I have a sparkling mineral water with the following properties listed:
400 mg/L Calcium
1400 mg/L Bicarbonate
If I freeze it, when it melts it becomes still, no longer fizzy. I understand this is due to CO2 coming out of solution. I'm guess this might be a result of both these reactions:
Ca(HCO3)2 --> CaCO3 + CO2 + H2O   [CaCO3 precipitates out, CO2 off-gasses]
H2CO3 --> CO2 + H2O [CO2 off-gasses]
Question: In the (now) still mineral water, will the bicarbonate or calcium content have changed?
If so, by approximately how much?

Was the bottle closed or open? Are you sure there was nothing else but calcium bicarbonate and extra carbon dioxide?

Hello, I deliberately froze the water the remove the fizz. So yes, it was carbonated to begin with, and I successfully removed the fizz. But I'm wondering what I've done to the Calcium and Bicarbonate content...
The water is Ferrarelle, and it has smaller amounts of some other minerals also (mg/L):
CALCIUM 400
SODIUM 52
POTASSIUM 49
MAGNESIUM 24
BICARBONATE 1452
CHLORIDE 16
SULPHATE 4.5
FLUORIDE 1.0
pH (UNITS) 6.1
COPPER 0.006
LEAD 0.0007
MANGANESE 0.07
NITRATE as Nitrogen 0.8

Technical note:  The further elaboration of original question, clarifying things or providing more info, is better to put to the question body, and eventually post a short comment notice about the update.

To remove the fizz, much better and faster is repeatedly shaking the bottle and carefully releasing CO2 and extra pressure, until it stops produce CO2. If it is in  PET, squeezing the bottle after CO2 release and before shaking decreases the number of needed cycles. //  Freezing and thawing the content is too aggressive toward drink chemistry and is also time + energy demanding.

I tried that first and it doesn't work. Much fizz remains after lots of shaking. Easier to freeze and defrost.

Some CO2 must remain, otherwise calcium and magnesium may start to precipitate as CaCO3/MgCO3/Mg(OH)2

I think the Ca Mg etc are initially there in bicarbonate form i.e. Ca(HCO3)2 etc. The CO2 that comes of, I'm supposing, is mainly from the carbonic acid (H2CO3) created when the water is artificially carbonated in the first place.

The now still mineral water contains a small amount of Calcium corresponding to the solubility product of $\ce{CaCO3}$, and this amount is about $\ce{5.3 * 10^{-4}}$ M, if the atmospheric pressure of $\ce{CO2}$ is $\ce{3.5 * 10^{-4}}$ atm at $\pu{T}$ = $25$° C.

Thanks, but how much Calcium never precipitated out in the first place (i.e. remained in solution as Ca(HCO3)2)? And how much bicarbonate remains? My guess is that Ca(HCO3)2 content is not much changed, and most of the CO2 off-gassing is from H2CO3 decomposition.

The amount of calcium that never precipitates is the amount of calcium corresponding to the solubility product. It is $\ce{5.3* 10^{-4}}$M.

I am referring to the Calcium contained in Ca(HCO3)2 that is there before (some of) it precipitates as CaCO3. I see your number refers only to CaCO3.
